# On the differentiability of max-type functions

Tags: convex-analysis

If $f(x, y)$ is strongly concave in $y$, then from Danskin's theorem we know that $\max_{y\in Y} f(x, y)$ is differentiable if $Y$ is convex and bounded. What if $Y$ is not bounded? Is $\max_{y\in Y} f(x, y)$ still differentiable? Any counter-example?

Comment: You should provide a reference to the statement of Danskin's theorem.

Comment: @Guojun Zhang there are many possible statements on the regularity of superior envelope. You should mention exactly the statement you want to prove/disprove.
I see there is a wiki article on a "Danskin's theorem"; unfortunately it has completely wrong statements.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz by strongly concave I meant there is a $\mu > 0$ such that for any $x$, $f(x, y) + (\mu/2) \|y\|^2$ is concave.